# Form elements styling

Tags: javascript, css

I wanna style all the form elements that normally cant be done in old browsers - so im asking does their exist a easy to use plugin in javascript that makes it easy to style

Check buttons - Radio buttons - select lists

(need to be supported in ie7 and 8)

A fiddle to do it would be nice

Comment: Specify the styling, not just "I need styling". You may be asking for something that isn't possible even with jQuery(UI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery UI is supported in IE7 and 8. It's probably the most popular plugin for this.

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer nice and easy